# Are there additional steps to enable SignUp with Social Account

Tags: django-allauth

This feels like a FAQ, but I've spent a few hours and I'm stuck. When you add facebook and twitter socialapps (following all the documented steps) Should you see these as options on the SignUp form without any additional steps? They did show up on the login form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did happen on its own after installing and configuring.
The way I ended up resolving this was to modify `templates/account/signup.html` so that it offered the signup with Social or Username\password

You need to load the social auth and then add a login button for each social auth provider you're using somewhere in the content block that makes sense in your layout.

```
{% load socialaccount %}

<div>
<a href="{% provider_login_url "twitter" process="connect" %}">
    Connect with Twitter</a>
</div>
<div>
<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" process="connect" %}">
    Connect with Facebook</a>
</div>
```